Why is pip install not working on arch arm?
When installing any package it produces a large error, its up to date from official pacman(pip 24.0). Im very new to linux and am not sure if im just being dumb or something. Im running Orange Pi os on a orange pi zero 2W 4gb ram, if thats any use.
When Running python3.12 -m pip install pn532pior pip install --user pn532pi this is the outcome.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 24, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
             ^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 77, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 114, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req import InstallRequirement
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.install.wheel import install_wheel
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 81, in <module>
    import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpclib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xmlrpc/client.py", line 138, in <module>
    from xml.parsers import expat
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: XML_SetReparseDeferralEnabled



maybe you have to use older Python with older modules.

I installed python-pipx as a system update and it seems to pass that error and moves to a package issue when installing pn532pi, but its progress.
